# How to convert buffer data to base64 image in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, blob, buffer, base64url

I got response data from API as a buffer data, I want to convert to base64 image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
  getBase64ImageFromURL(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var img = new Image();
      img.setAttribute("crossOrigin", "anonymous");

      img.onload = () => {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        resolve(dataURL);
      };

      img.onerror = error => {
        reject(error);
      };

      img.src = url;
    });
  }
```

You can use this function as follows:

```
async someFunction() { 
  const logo = await this.getBase64ImageFromURL("logo.jpg");
 }
```